# What is 8 times 9 in 12-hour clock arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is $8\times 9$ in $12$ hour arithmetic?

Will it be $0$, or will it be $6$?

$8*9 = 72$ and $72/12 = 6$

So is the answer $0$ or $6$?

Comment: Is $12$ the same as $0$ or $1$ in clock arithmetic?

Comment: If instead of $72$ you had $73$ for which $73 / 12 = 6.08333333333\dots$, what would you say the answer is?

Answer (score 5):

Modular arithmetic deals with remainders upon division.  The remainder of $72$ upon dividing by $12$ is $0$.  So we have

$$8\cdot9\equiv72\equiv0\operatorname{mod}12$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember,
$$a\equiv b\bmod n\;\iff \;n\text{ goes into }a-b,$$
or in other words,
$$a\equiv b\bmod n\;\iff \;\text{dividing }a-b\text{ by }n\text{ leaves no remainder}.$$
Using this definition, which statement is true:
$$72\equiv 0\bmod 12$$
or
$$\;\;\;72\equiv 6\bmod 12 \;?$$

Comment: So it is definitely O as 12 divides 72 and not 66.Isn't it?

Comment: Yup, that's right!